# Linq Query Won't Work In Reverse

Tags: c#, linq

I have a pretty simple structure I'm working with.

Customers make Purchases

The tables are related in SQL and I can get the results using:

```
from p in Purchases
where p.Price > 1000
where p.Customer.Name == "Mary"
select new 
{
    p.Customer.Name,
    p.Description,
    p.Price
}
```

However, if I reverse the order of the tables and select from Customers first, it gives an error.

```
from c in Customers
where c.Name == "Mary"
where c.Purchases.Price > 1000
select new
{
    c.Name,
    c.Purchases.Description,
    c.Purchases.Price
}
```

Putting the query in LINQPad highlights the `where c.Purchases.Price > 1000` line as the problem and the error message is:

> System.Data.Linq.EntitySet' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Price' and no extension method 'Price' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet' could be found
>   (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

Why can I get the data by going through Purchases, but not by going through the Customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `c.Purchases` is a *collection* of purchases and does not have a single `Price` property.

You *could* join customers to purchases and get all results where `p.Price > 1000`, but then you have to repeat the join clause that the navigation property hides:

```
from c in Customers
join p in Purchases on c.Id equals p.CustoimerId
where c.Name == "Mary" && p.Price > 1000
select new
{
    c.Name,
    p.Description,
    p.Price
}
```

Comment: So it's because of the cardinality of the relationship? Because the Purchases is on the Many side of the relationship, it is a collection and can't be interacted with directly without explicitly joining the tables? But the first example, I'm interacting with the Customers on the One side of the relationship it is fine?

Comment: Yes - there is one customer for a purchase so you can access its properties directly.